# No 'cancel' option for user in PayPal 'Donate' workflow

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I'm using the auto-generated Paypal 'Donate Button' code.  Everything works great, but if the user has second thoughts before confirming their donation, there isn't a 'Cancel' or 'Back' option shown in the workflow pages.  Does the user need to use the browser 'back' button?  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the button in PayPal you need to specify the URL to send the user to when they cancel - this is an option at Step 3 of the creation process.